Find corner points of contour without any external library Like openCV
I want to find the corner point of the contour in android studio java. I got the contour point by using some custome method. I'm using the below code for finding the corner points of the contour.
public static Point[] findExtremePoints(List<Point> contourPoints) {
        if (contourPoints.isEmpty()) {
            return null; // Return null if the contour is empty
        }

        // Initialize extreme points with the first point in the contour
        Point leftmost = contourPoints.get(0);
        Point rightmost = contourPoints.get(0);
        Point topmost = contourPoints.get(0);
        Point bottommost = contourPoints.get(0);

        // Find extreme points by iterating through all points in the contour
        for (Point point : contourPoints) {
            if (point.x < leftmost.x || (point.x == leftmost.x && point.y < leftmost.y)) {
                leftmost = point; // Update leftmost point
            }
            if (point.x > rightmost.x || (point.x == rightmost.x && point.y > rightmost.y)) {
                rightmost = point; // Update rightmost point
            }
            if (point.y < topmost.y || (point.y == topmost.y && point.x < topmost.x)) {
                topmost = point; // Update topmost point
            }
            if (point.y > bottommost.y || (point.y == bottommost.y && point.x > bottommost.x)) {
                bottommost = point; // Update bottommost point
            }
        }

        // Return the extreme points as an array
        return new Point[]{leftmost, rightmost, topmost, bottommost};
    }

But this code some times does not provoid corner points.
For example this case : .
In that case I got a answer is {(161, 694), (583, 705), (241, 435), (582, 706)}.
But I had to get (502, 439) this point.
Can any one explain what is the mistake I done in that code.

You did not "attach an image with this", and please don't, give us the actual list of points in the post itself, preferably as a [mcve]. At first glance, your algorithm only works if the list of points actually contains the corner points of the rectangle, if they don't you need to get the min/max X/Y coordinates separately.
